# disable launcher icons in another workspace

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, workspaces

I use one workspace for watching movies and another workspace for my work.
I don't want that folder icon opened in one workspace to be displayed in other workspace  i.e.[my first workspace in which I have opened firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOEBx.png) and [my 2nd workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i249X.png)  .
How can I remove the highlighted firefox in 2nd workspace?

I am using ubuntu 14.04